# Removing duplicates that occur within a timedelta

Tags: python-polars

I have timestamps of when a product was viewed, and am interested in removing duplicates that occur within the first ten minutes of the previous non-duplicate timestamp (these can be due to the user refreshing the page). I also want to preserve the metadata associated with each product.

To be very clear: If a specific product is first viewed at time = 25 min, and then again at time = 30 min, then the second instance is considered a duplicate and should be removed. If there is a further view of the *same* product at time = 26 min, then this new view is more than ten min after the previous non-duplicate view, and should therefore be kept.

```py
from datetime import datetime
import polars as pl

df = pl.DataFrame(
    {
        "created_time": [
            datetime(2023, 1, 1, 0, 0),
            datetime(2023, 1, 1, 0, 1),
            datetime(2023, 1, 1, 0, 2),
            datetime(2023, 1, 1, 0, 3),
            datetime(2023, 1, 1, 0, 11),
            datetime(2023, 1, 1, 0, 29),
            datetime(2023, 1, 1, 0, 31),
        ],
        "product_id": [1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1],
        "metadata":["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g"]
    }
)


df_desirable = pl.DataFrame(
    {
        "created_time": [
            datetime(2023, 1, 1, 0, 0),
            datetime(2023, 1, 1, 0, 2),
            datetime(2023, 1, 1, 0, 11),
            datetime(2023, 1, 1, 0, 29),
        ],
        "product_id": [1, 2, 1, 1],
        "metadata":["a", "c", "e", "f"]
    }
)
```

Raw data

```py
print(df)
shape: (7, 3)
┌─────────────────────┬────────────┬──────────┐
│ created_time        ┆ product_id ┆ metadata │
│ ---                 ┆ ---        ┆ ---      │
│ datetime[μs]        ┆ i64        ┆ str      │
╞═════════════════════╪════════════╪══════════╡
│ 2023-01-01 00:00:00 ┆ 1          ┆ a        │
│ 2023-01-01 00:01:00 ┆ 1          ┆ b        │
│ 2023-01-01 00:02:00 ┆ 2          ┆ c        │
│ 2023-01-01 00:03:00 ┆ 1          ┆ d        │
│ 2023-01-01 00:11:00 ┆ 1          ┆ e        │
│ 2023-01-01 00:29:00 ┆ 1          ┆ f        │
│ 2023-01-01 00:31:00 ┆ 1          ┆ g        │
└─────────────────────┴────────────┴──────────┘
```

Desired output

```py
print(df_desirable)
shape: (4, 3)
┌─────────────────────┬────────────┬──────────┐
│ created_time        ┆ product_id ┆ metadata │
│ ---                 ┆ ---        ┆ ---      │
│ datetime[μs]        ┆ i64        ┆ str      │
╞═════════════════════╪════════════╪══════════╡
│ 2023-01-01 00:00:00 ┆ 1          ┆ a        │
│ 2023-01-01 00:02:00 ┆ 2          ┆ c        │
│ 2023-01-01 00:11:00 ┆ 1          ┆ e        │
│ 2023-01-01 00:29:00 ┆ 1          ┆ f        │
└─────────────────────┴────────────┴──────────┘
```

In the above raw data, the first row is not a duplicate, because there are no timestamps with product_id = 1 within 10 minutes before it (there are no rows at all before it). Naming them by metadata now, row `b` is duplicate because it occurs within 10 min of `a`. `c` is a new product_id and not duplicate. `d` is duplicate, being within 10 min after `a`. `e` is not duplicate, because it is more than 10 min after `a`. `f` is not duplicate, because it is more than 10 min after `e`. `g` is duplicate, because it is less than 10 min after `f`, which is the previous non-duplicate.

I've considered grouping by the `product_id`, but then I'm not sure how to correctly remove the entries for `product_id == 1` at minutes 1 and 2 in the example below.

I've also considered using something like:

```py
from datetime import timedelta
df.groupby_dynamic("created_time", every=timedelta(minutes=10))
```

but I'm not sure how to remove the rows correctly here either.

Could someone help?

Comment: The row with `metadata` = `g` is a duplicate that occurred 31 minutes (> 10 min.) after the initial page view. This appears to meet your criteria for keeping the record. However, the desired `DataFrame` does not include this row. Could you clarify if row `g` should be dropped in the desired output?

Comment: I've added an explanation for each row. `g` should be dropped because it is within ten minutes after `f`, which is a non-duplicate row because `f` is more than ten minutes after `e`.

Comment: Your explanations clearly address this. Thank you for this additional info!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if I'm over-complicating things here - but it looks like a [`.join_asof`](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/dataframe/api/polars.DataFrame.join_asof.html#polars.DataFrame.join_asof) type problem to me.

(**note:** the `created_time` column must be sorted)

```
df.join_asof(
   df.with_columns(window = pl.col("created_time") + pl.duration(minutes=10)),
   left_on="created_time",
   right_on="window",
   by="product_id",
   strategy="forward"
)
```

```
shape: (7, 6)
┌─────────────────────┬────────────┬──────────┬─────────────────────┬────────────────┬─────────────────────┐
│ created_time        | product_id | metadata | created_time_right  | metadata_right | window              │
│ ---                 | ---        | ---      | ---                 | ---            | ---                 │
│ datetime[μs]        | i64        | str      | datetime[μs]        | str            | datetime[μs]        │
╞═════════════════════╪════════════╪══════════╪═════════════════════╪════════════════╪═════════════════════╡
│ 2023-01-01 00:00:00 | 1          | a        | 2023-01-01 00:00:00 | a              | 2023-01-01 00:10:00 │
│ 2023-01-01 00:01:00 | 1          | b        | 2023-01-01 00:00:00 | a              | 2023-01-01 00:10:00 │
│ 2023-01-01 00:02:00 | 2          | c        | 2023-01-01 00:02:00 | c              | 2023-01-01 00:12:00 │
│ 2023-01-01 00:03:00 | 1          | d        | 2023-01-01 00:00:00 | a              | 2023-01-01 00:10:00 │
│ 2023-01-01 00:11:00 | 1          | e        | 2023-01-01 00:01:00 | b              | 2023-01-01 00:11:00 │
│ 2023-01-01 00:29:00 | 1          | f        | 2023-01-01 00:29:00 | f              | 2023-01-01 00:39:00 │
│ 2023-01-01 00:31:00 | 1          | g        | 2023-01-01 00:29:00 | f              | 2023-01-01 00:39:00 │
└─────────────────────┴────────────┴──────────┴─────────────────────┴────────────────┴─────────────────────┘
```

You can then `.groupby("product_id", "window")` and take the `.first()` from row each group.

```
(df
 .join_asof(
     df.with_columns(window = pl.col("created_time") + pl.duration(minutes=10)),
     left_on="created_time",
     right_on="window",
     by="product_id",
     strategy="forward")
 .groupby("product_id", "window")
 .first())
```

```
shape: (4, 6)
┌────────────┬─────────────────────┬─────────────────────┬──────────┬─────────────────────┬────────────────┐
│ product_id | window              | created_time        | metadata | created_time_right  | metadata_right │
│ ---        | ---                 | ---                 | ---      | ---                 | ---            │
│ i64        | datetime[μs]        | datetime[μs]        | str      | datetime[μs]        | str            │
╞════════════╪═════════════════════╪═════════════════════╪══════════╪═════════════════════╪════════════════╡
│ 1          | 2023-01-01 00:10:00 | 2023-01-01 00:00:00 | a        | 2023-01-01 00:00:00 | a              │
│ 1          | 2023-01-01 00:11:00 | 2023-01-01 00:11:00 | e        | 2023-01-01 00:01:00 | b              │
│ 1          | 2023-01-01 00:39:00 | 2023-01-01 00:29:00 | f        | 2023-01-01 00:29:00 | f              │
│ 2          | 2023-01-01 00:12:00 | 2023-01-01 00:02:00 | c        | 2023-01-01 00:02:00 | c              │
└────────────┴─────────────────────┴─────────────────────┴──────────┴─────────────────────┴────────────────┘
```

You can add `maintain_order=True` to the groupby if you want to keep the original order.

```
(df
 .join_asof(
     df.with_columns(window = pl.col("created_time") + pl.duration(minutes=10)),
     left_on="created_time",
     right_on="window",
     by="product_id",
     strategy="forward")
 .groupby("product_id", "window", maintain_order=True)
 .first())
```

```
shape: (4, 6)
┌────────────┬─────────────────────┬─────────────────────┬──────────┬─────────────────────┬────────────────┐
│ product_id ┆ window              ┆ created_time        ┆ metadata ┆ created_time_right  ┆ metadata_right │
│ ---        ┆ ---                 ┆ ---                 ┆ ---      ┆ ---                 ┆ ---            │
│ i64        ┆ datetime[μs]        ┆ datetime[μs]        ┆ str      ┆ datetime[μs]        ┆ str            │
╞════════════╪═════════════════════╪═════════════════════╪══════════╪═════════════════════╪════════════════╡
│ 1          ┆ 2023-01-01 00:10:00 ┆ 2023-01-01 00:00:00 ┆ a        ┆ 2023-01-01 00:00:00 ┆ a              │
│ 2          ┆ 2023-01-01 00:12:00 ┆ 2023-01-01 00:02:00 ┆ c        ┆ 2023-01-01 00:02:00 ┆ c              │
│ 1          ┆ 2023-01-01 00:11:00 ┆ 2023-01-01 00:11:00 ┆ e        ┆ 2023-01-01 00:01:00 ┆ b              │
│ 1          ┆ 2023-01-01 00:39:00 ┆ 2023-01-01 00:29:00 ┆ f        ┆ 2023-01-01 00:29:00 ┆ f              │
└────────────┴─────────────────────┴─────────────────────┴──────────┴─────────────────────┴────────────────┘
```

Comment: This is a great answer and a very cool solution!

Comment: It's actually quite an interesting question with how it can be interpreted in various different ways. I wasn't entirely sure it was solving the "correct" interpretation.

Comment: Just wondering, in order to be certain that we're picking the "earliest" first entry after the groupby, shouldn't we sort after the groupby?

`.agg(pl.all().sort_by("created_time").first())`, instead of `.first()`?

Comment: Perhaps it's better to use `.groupby("product_id", "window", maintain_order=True)` - groupby doesn't maintain the output order by default. That is the order being lost, not the order of the rows inside each group.

Comment: Your suggestion would maintain the order of the groups as they were in the upstream `df`, but we already account for by sorting later. I was thinking of the order within the groups. But maybe that is handled implicitly from the way join_asof works?

Comment: Yes, that order is handled implicitly.

Answer (score 1):

IIUC, there could be two types of duplicates per product

1. page views within 10 minutes of the initial page view
2. page views within 10 minutes of the previous page view

So, one possible approach is to filter out each type of duplicate separately, in a two-step process.

First, remove duplicates within 10 minutes of the initial page view per product (use `polars` window functions with `.min()`, which will capture the first page view per product)

```py
df_no_1st_view_dups = (
    df
    # add duration since first viewing of a product_id page
    .with_columns(
        (pl.col("created_time") - pl.col("created_time").min())
        .over(pl.col("product_id"))
        .alias("t_since_1st_view"),
    )
    # keep views that occurred more than 10 min. after initial view
    # (also keep initial view, which has duration = 0us)
    .filter(
        (pl.col("t_since_1st_view") == 0)
        | (pl.col("t_since_1st_view") > pl.duration(minutes=10))
    )
)
print(df_no_1st_view_dups)
shape: (5, 4)
┌─────────────────────┬────────────┬──────────┬──────────────────┐
│ created_time        ┆ product_id ┆ metadata ┆ t_since_1st_view │
│ ---                 ┆ ---        ┆ ---      ┆ ---              │
│ datetime[μs]        ┆ i64        ┆ str      ┆ duration[μs]     │
╞═════════════════════╪════════════╪══════════╪══════════════════╡
│ 2023-01-01 00:00:00 ┆ 1          ┆ a        ┆ 0µs              │
│ 2023-01-01 00:02:00 ┆ 2          ┆ c        ┆ 0µs              │
│ 2023-01-01 00:11:00 ┆ 1          ┆ e        ┆ 11m              │
│ 2023-01-01 00:29:00 ┆ 1          ┆ f        ┆ 29m              │
│ 2023-01-01 00:31:00 ┆ 1          ┆ g        ┆ 31m              │
└─────────────────────┴────────────┴──────────┴──────────────────┘
```

Next, add a column (`t_since_prev_view`) to indicate time since the previous page view, using `.diff()` (in the following step, this column is used to filter out these duplicates)

```py
df_no_1st_view_dups_with_prev_view_filter = (
    df_no_1st_view_dups
    # add duration since previous (non-duplicated) page view
    .with_columns(
        [
            (pl.col("t_since_1st_view").diff())
            .over(pl.col("product_id"))
            .alias("t_since_prev_view")
        ]
    )
)
print(df_no_1st_view_dups_with_prev_view_filter)
shape: (5, 5)
┌─────────────────────┬────────────┬──────────┬──────────────────┬───────────────────┐
│ created_time        ┆ product_id ┆ metadata ┆ t_since_1st_view ┆ t_since_prev_view │
│ ---                 ┆ ---        ┆ ---      ┆ ---              ┆ ---               │
│ datetime[μs]        ┆ i64        ┆ str      ┆ duration[μs]     ┆ duration[μs]      │
╞═════════════════════╪════════════╪══════════╪══════════════════╪═══════════════════╡
│ 2023-01-01 00:00:00 ┆ 1          ┆ a        ┆ 0µs              ┆ null              │
│ 2023-01-01 00:02:00 ┆ 2          ┆ c        ┆ 0µs              ┆ null              │
│ 2023-01-01 00:11:00 ┆ 1          ┆ e        ┆ 11m              ┆ 11m               │
│ 2023-01-01 00:29:00 ┆ 1          ┆ f        ┆ 29m              ┆ 18m               │
│ 2023-01-01 00:31:00 ┆ 1          ┆ g        ┆ 31m              ┆ 2m                │
└─────────────────────┴────────────┴──────────┴──────────────────┴───────────────────┘
```

Finally, filter based on this new column (`t_since_prev_view`) to eliminate views within 10 minutes of the previous (non-duplicated) page view

```py
df_filtered = (
    df_no_1st_view_dups_with_prev_view_filter
    # keep views that occured more than 10 min. after previous view
    # (also keep the non-duplicated view, which has duration = NULL)
    .filter(
        (pl.col("t_since_prev_view") == None)
        | (pl.col("t_since_prev_view") > pl.duration(minutes=10))
    )
)
print(df_filtered)
shape: (4, 5)
┌─────────────────────┬────────────┬──────────┬──────────────────┬───────────────────┐
│ created_time        ┆ product_id ┆ metadata ┆ t_since_1st_view ┆ t_since_prev_view │
│ ---                 ┆ ---        ┆ ---      ┆ ---              ┆ ---               │
│ datetime[μs]        ┆ i64        ┆ str      ┆ duration[μs]     ┆ duration[μs]      │
╞═════════════════════╪════════════╪══════════╪══════════════════╪═══════════════════╡
│ 2023-01-01 00:00:00 ┆ 1          ┆ a        ┆ 0µs              ┆ null              │
│ 2023-01-01 00:02:00 ┆ 2          ┆ c        ┆ 0µs              ┆ null              │
│ 2023-01-01 00:11:00 ┆ 1          ┆ e        ┆ 11m              ┆ 11m               │
│ 2023-01-01 00:29:00 ┆ 1          ┆ f        ┆ 29m              ┆ 18m               │
└─────────────────────┴────────────┴──────────┴──────────────────┴───────────────────┘
```

(Optional) Drop the unwanted time duration columns

```py
df_filtered = df_filtered.drop(["t_since_1st_view", "t_since_prev_view"])
print(df_filtered)
shape: (4, 3)
┌─────────────────────┬────────────┬──────────┐
│ created_time        ┆ product_id ┆ metadata │
│ ---                 ┆ ---        ┆ ---      │
│ datetime[μs]        ┆ i64        ┆ str      │
╞═════════════════════╪════════════╪══════════╡
│ 2023-01-01 00:00:00 ┆ 1          ┆ a        │
│ 2023-01-01 00:02:00 ┆ 2          ┆ c        │
│ 2023-01-01 00:11:00 ┆ 1          ┆ e        │
│ 2023-01-01 00:29:00 ┆ 1          ┆ f        │
└─────────────────────┴────────────┴──────────┘
```

I think this approach gets the desired output in the question. It preserves the metadata and removes the duplicated product page views.